# Navigation Menu Distorts On Zoom In/Out

Tags: html, css

please consider the [link to my website](http://goo.gl/hMzbr1)
The navigation menu distorts upon zoom in/out. I have tried everything i could do like changing widths or paddings or font-size from px to em/% but no matter whatevery i try, the menu keeps on distorting. I have also tried the [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818506/when-i-zoom-out-web-4-div-go-down-to-next-line) and [this tutorial](http://jamesowers.co.uk/css-tutorials/10/vertical-list-menu/) but i can't get it to the fix. Please help me out

Comment: Are you referring to zooming on a mobile device?  I see nothing strange on a desktop in chrome.

Comment: zooming mean ctrl + scroll up/down